# jQuery Show anc css opacity

Tags: jquery, css, show, opacity

I have problem with jQuery and transparency

I use jQuery for show div onmouseover and hide onmouseout as in this case :

```
function carrousel_cover_up(id)
{
   jQuery(".c_cover_"+id).show(1000).delay(3000).hide(2000);

   if (id=="")
   {
      jQuery(".c_cover_"+id).hide(10);
   }
}
```

The script in jQuery works fine, the problem is the css for div have this :

```
background: rgb(200%, 54%, 54%);
background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5);
```

And when show div the transparency disappears and no show opacity , only happen with internet explorer with the other browsers works very fine and I can see the objects behind divs when show onmouseover

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: IE doesn't have support for rgba, but does support Alpha channels if you use filters

Comment: I use and no works with alpha i use IE 11

Comment: `{
background: transparent;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7FC83636,endColorstr=#7FC83636)"; /* IE8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7FC83636,endColorstr=#7FC83636);   /* IE6 & 7 */
      zoom: 1;
}`

Comment: IE also supports the opacity style in css (if you're trying to make the div itself appear and disappear and not just the div's background)